# How to find all singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following:

Find and classify all singularities of $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$

My calculations:
It seems obvious that one candidate would be $z_0=1$
Looking at the Laurent series around $z_0=1$,

$e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z-1)^n} \frac{1}{n!}$,

which yields that $z_0=1$ is an essential singularity.
I think this is the only singularity. How can one proof that there are no more singularities. (In $\mathbb{R}$ one was at least able to look at its graph to be sure)

Comment: Isn't composition of two holomorphic functions holomorphic? $1/(z-1)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$ and $e^z$ is entire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{z-1}$ is holomorphic, and especially defined, on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$, this can be prooven by showing that the jacobian matrix fullfills the CR Equations. $e$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ since its taylor series converges everywhere. Therfore your function is the composition of two holomorphic functions, and therfore holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$.

Usually you approach such a question in this way, you check where the function can be defined and then you calculate where it can be holomorphic, often argumenting with compositions.

Also you are of course correct about the type of singularity in $1$.